# find the codomain of $f(z)=Log \frac{z-1}{z+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having struggle to find the codomain of $$f(z)=\operatorname{Log}\frac{z-1}{z+1}$$
with the condition of $\operatorname{Im}(z)>0$.

I've found the domain of a function to be: $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$ using Möbius transformation where $w=T(z)= \frac {z-1}{z+1}$ and than: $z= \frac {w+1}{1-w}$ but I'm not sure if this helps me at all.

Comment: One way to visualize the effect of a Moebius transformation is to write it as a composition of (rotation and homothety) $z\mapsto az$, (translation) $z\mapsto z+b$, (inversion plus reflection with respect to the real axis) $z\mapsto 1/z$. In your case, carrying out the division with remainder, $\frac{z-1}{z+1}=1-\frac{2}{z+1}$. So, it is a composition of $z\mapsto z+1$, $z\mapsto -2z$ and $z\mapsto z+1$.

Comment: Hint: Composition of mappings

Comment: $T(z)$ maps the upper half plane to the upper half plane, so you just need to find the range of $\log z = |z| +i\arg z$ where $\Im(z)\ge 0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You sure? I think $T(i) =i$.

Comment: Whoops, I got it wrong, thogught it was $1-z$ in the numerator. @Tavish I was staring right at it and calculated it as $T(i)=\frac{1-i}{1+i}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I can only imagine.

Comment: The domain can actually include $z\in(0,1)$ too. If you didn’t have a condition of $\operatorname{Im}z\geq$ you could only have a domain of $\mathbb C\setminus\[0,1]$ and keep $f$ continuous. But you can define $f$ continuous in $$\{z\mid \operatorname{Im} z\geq 0\}\setminus\{0,1\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**For the domain**

The domain can actually include $z\in(-1,1)$ too. If you didn’t have a condition of $\operatorname{Im}z\geq 0$ you could only have a domain of $\mathbb C\setminus[-1,1]$ and keep $f$ continuous. But you can define $f$ continuous on $$\{z\mid \operatorname{Im} z\geq 0\}\setminus\{-1,1\}.$$

**Hints for range:**

It is smart to start with $T.$

1. What is the image $T(\mathbb R)?$
2. On which side of that image does the image of the other part of the domain, $\{z\mid \operatorname{Im}z>0\}$ lie?

Comment: what does its mean $C∪{∞}$? 
if I plug in $T(\mathbb{R})$ do I get: $w=T(z=x+i0)=\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ ?

Comment: Ah, I assumed you had converted $\mathbb C\cup \{\infty\}$ because it is often covered with Möbius transformations.  Instead ask: What is the image of $\mathbb R$ under $T?$ @David

Comment: I'm really trying to understand (I also traslate it to english) I don't know what it's means $C∪{∞}$ also, am I was wrong? $T(\mathbb{R})=\frac {x-1}{x+1}$?

Comment: $T(\mathbb R)$ is the range of $T$ applied to $\mathbb R.$ $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ is a function, so, it is not a range. What are all values $T(x)$ where $x$ is real?

Comment: all the values of $T(x)$ if x is real are real numbers?

Comment: Well, sure, if you want to solve that way, then you could define the range of $f$ as all $f(z)$ where $z$ is in your codomain. If $x$ is real, for example, $T(x)$ is real. What subset of $\mathbb R$ is the range $T(\mathbb R)?$

Comment: but any real number is inside the range

Comment: i have just read that:
1. range of $T(x)$ is the unit circle.
2.  also the image of $Im(z)>0$ is the unit circle.

Comment: The range $T(\mathbb R)$ is not the unit circle. It couldn’t be, since $T(x)$ is real if $x$ is real. In particular, $T(2)=\frac13.$ @David Use your inverse to figure out what $w$ can and cannot be.

Comment: if $Im(z)>0$ so w must be as well $Im(w)>0$